# how do we call a c function from an sql script

Tags: sql, c, plsql

how do we call a C function from an SQL script?

```
int get_next_fbill_b2kId_seq_num(b2kIdType seq_val,bankIdPtrType bank_id)
{
    validate_dc_alias(dcAlias);
    tbaDateType sysDate;
    tbaGetSystemDateTime(sysDate,NULL,NULL);  /* returns in TBA date format */
    sysDate[10] = EOS;
    get_seq_value(next_num_char, 0, FBILL_B2KID_SRL_NUM,bank_id,TBAFATAL);
    m_sprintf (seq_val, "%s%s%s", dcAlias, sysDate+8,next_num_char);

    return(SUCCESS);
}
```

This is my function defined in a cxx file.
I want to call this in an SQL script.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the OP uses Oracle because he/she writes about PL/SQL.

It is possible to call an external c procedure. http://www.shutdownabort.com/quickguides/c_extproc.php

Answer (score 0):

If your function is plain C, you need to create an executable and invoke it via [! or HOST](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.21_and_HOST.3F).

If you are in a .Net environment, you can also create a .Net assembly containing your code, and [call your procedure](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/mastering_dotnet_oracle/williams_sps.html) as if it was a PL/SQL procedure.